# How to set proerties for Chrome.exe - Need to replace the shortcut argument

Tags: google-chrome

I created a shortcut for Chrome.exe and passed the arguments --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session"

However the arguments works fine when clicking the shortcuts and able to see the security got disabled.

However i want this change to be permanent....no matter how many shortcuts pointing to the chrome, the arguments should get executed automatically

Does argument can be set in any chrome property files ?

Please advise

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One Solution is touching the registry. However don't want to touch it and looking for a solution without touching registry

```
Example, 
   Firefox to run with the parameters "-p username" when I run "firefox.exe"
   https://superuser.com/questions/12230/how-to-set-default-parameters-for-an-application

Run regedit and take a look at the key:

  `My Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\FirefoxHTML\shell\open\command`

  Put -p username into the command string at the appropriate place.
```

Thanks.